# Googleads python module - how to create class instances

Tags: python, google-dfp

I'm using python 2.7 and the google dfp api python module (googleads-4.4.0).

The doubleclick for publishers documentation (https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/rel_notes) describes 'types' (aka classes) like CustomTargetingValue. I want to create new instances of such classes so that I can populate them and call the API-accessible methods like createCustomTargetingValues() on them.

I would expect to create new instances by using the class name and 'call' method.

```
newVal = CustomTargetingValue()
```

... but this generates an NameError

```
NameError: name 'CustomTargetingValue' is not defined
```

I've tried digging around with dir(), vars() and inspect, but I could not find a a way that works to qualify the name, e.g. googleads.CustomTargetingValue, suds.sudsobject.CustomTargetingValue.

As a workaround, I can use a DFP query like getCustomTargetingValuesByStatement() to return an existing object of the type I want, use 'type' to get its class, and then use the call method

```
newVal=type(existingVal)()
```

I can similarly use the copy module to replicate the object, but both ways seem like hacks.

I've obviously missed something blindingly obvious here - what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Hi, any solution for this problem? I kinda having the same atm.

Comment: No, amazingly not! I find that I'm usually working on objects that I get from a getXbyStatement call, so it's OK. Otherwise I either make a call to get a template object and change values, or build one from scratch per the code examples. Let me know if you find out any more!

Comment: I think I would use the Answer section as I will posted code there. Let me do that. I think --cmiiw-- I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution that I found is simply composed a dictionary with the proper `xsi_type` and making sure all the mandatory fields are supplied. This dictionary then get supplied to the DFP api call being made.I particularly enlightened by [this code example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/dfp/v201705/line_item_service/target_custom_criteria.py#L77).

So, for example I need to add a new top level KVP (CustomCriteriaSet), I use this code:

```
new_kvp = {
    'xsi_type': 'CustomCriteriaSet',
    'logicalOperator': 'AND',
    'children': {
        'xsi_type': 'CustomCriteria',
        'keyId': key_id,
        'valueIds': [value1_id,value2_id],
        'operator': 'IS_NOT'
        }
    }
l.targeting['customTargeting'] = new_kvp
updated_li.append(l)
...
li_service.updateLineItems(updated_li)
...
```

Although I found in a PHP example [here](https://github.com/RayViljoen/Auto-DFP/blob/master/api/examples/v201108/LineItemService/TargetCustomCriteriaExample.php#L87),the code simply made a call to `CustomCriteriaSet` call, but I can't find the similar code in Python examples though. Probably just a helper class, but I am not yet checking that PHP examples.

Well, this solution work for me anyway. So I'll go with this.